# Error "preg_match_all" with Wordpress SEO by Yoast plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I hope someone could realy help me...

I get this error message :

```
"error Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'I' in /home/sulistyo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/linkdex/linkdex.php on line 476"
```

when I enter/write a focus keyword on wordpress seo meta box.

I don't know what to do to solve the error. I hope someone or the developer of the plugin (Joost de Valk) could help me with this error - thanks.

I really need your help...

Answer (score 1):

I browsed through all the versions available here http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/tags/ and nowhere is there any "I" modifier. The "I" modifier is [obviously](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) invalid, thus the error. Updating the plugin will most certainly solve the issue. Or at least, if updates are not possible, edit line 476 of */wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/linkdex/linkdex.php* and turn

```
$keywordCount = preg_match_all("/".$job["keyword"]."/msIU", $body, $res);
```

or whatever it may have to:

```
$keywordCount = preg_match_all("/".$job["keyword"]."/msiU", $body, $res);
```

**An update**:

After you mentioned 'P' being an invalid modifier, it suddenly struck me that the keyword is not escaped and that you may be using a backslash `/` inside of there, breaking the regular expression.

While you're waiting for an update you can rewrite the line to:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/trunk/admin/linkdex/linkdex.php#L476

```
$keywordCount = preg_match_all("#".$job["keyword"]."#msIU", $body, $res);
```

Note how I changed the `/` to `#` delimiters, you're probably not going to use those, so your expression will not fail.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Alternatively you can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) like so:

```
$keywordCount = preg_match_all("/".preg_quote($job["keyword"], '/')."/msIU", $body, $res);
```

Comment: Joost de Valk has been notified, issue should be taken care of soon. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Soulseekah for your answer. i've checked on my /wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/linkdex/linkdex.php and what is written there is just exactly the same as you mention/write above, i have : $keywordCount = preg_match_all("/".$job["keyword"]."/msiU", $body, $res); and i don't know what and where the problem is. I try to copy and replace and still nothing happen, the second time i try to re-save my fokus keyword on my post the error was still occur but with different message : "error Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'p' in /home/sulistyo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/linkdex/linkdex.php on line 476". For information : this error only occur on one of post only, while the plugin seem to be work well on my others posts. btw, thanks for your answer.. , thank very much...

Comment: Does your job keyword have a slash in it? Can you `var_dump($job["keyword"]);` and check please?

Comment: @Soulseekah: where i should check it..

Comment: Just below that 476 line, write a new line and `var_dump($job["keyword"]); exit();` then navigate over to the page that gives you the error and see what the keyword was, I'm assuming it has a slash in it...

Comment: What keyword are you entering to get that error?

Comment: thanks,i'll try, yes you're right that the my focus keyword (that give me an error) has  a slash.

Comment: It's a bug then. Wait for an update.

Comment: @Soulseekah: windows 7 tcp/ip

Comment: @Soulseekah:thank very much, you save my day, i really apreciate your attention... thank you......